Restart systemd service when dependency starts
I have a systemd service foo which depends on another service bar with both After= and Requires=. Both services are configured with Restart=on-failure. Sometimes foo takes a few tries to start successfully because its dependencies are not ready. After foo fails one time, bar enters a failed state. How can I make bar try to start again after foo finishes?  Below is a snippet from journalctl showing the order of operations.
Nov 10 21:25:27 r3002638 systemd[1]: Starting foo...
Nov 10 21:25:34 r3002638 systemd[1]: foo.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
Nov 10 21:25:34 r3002638 systemd[1]: foo.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 10 21:25:34 r3002638 systemd[1]: Failed to start foo
Nov 10 21:25:34 r3002638 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for bar.
Nov 10 21:25:34 r3002638 systemd[1]: bar.service: Job bar.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Nov 10 21:25:34 r3002638 systemd[1]: foo.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Nov 10 21:25:34 r3002638 systemd[1]: Stopped foo.
Nov 10 21:25:34 r3002638 systemd[1]: Starting foo...
Nov 10 21:25:47 r3002638 systemd[1]: Finished foo.



I believe you can modify foo.service to include BindsTo=bar.service as well as adding Restart=always in bar.service, you can achieve what you want.

BindsTo= in foo.service: This directive will bind the lifecycle of foo to bar. If foo fails, systemd will re-evaluate the dependency and try to start bar as needed. (BindsTo is partially explained in this ServerFault question)

Restart=always is self explanatory. If you put it in bar.service it ensures that bar restarts whenever there is a failed dependency, (hopefully) making sure bar attempts to restart each time foo does.


Now I know I don’t have any concrete evidence to support this, but I’m fairly sure it’ll work, and it definitely won’t hurt to try.
